# There is a problem parsing oldVersion attribute DotVVM.Core

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2022, assembly-binding-redirect, dotvvm

In Visual Studio 2022, I have created a new DotVVM project, including Bootstrap 3 and jQuery.
As I am evaluating the pros/cons of DotVVM I check the create sample pages options.
The issue I have is that when building the project I get the following message.

> Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. There was a
> problem parsing the oldVersion attribute. Version string portion was
> too short or too long.

The lines referred to are

```
<assemblyIdentity name="DotVVM.Core" publicKeyToken="23f3607db32275da" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0.0"/>
```

I have researched the error message and found a post on
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/application-configuration-file-webconfig-is-invali/793847

which states that the error was "Fixed In: Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3". I still have VS 2019 installed so I tried to build the project in that. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are too many zeros in the versions - the version format is `x.x.x.x`.

The correct one is this:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0"/>
```